# Is there a simpler way to process check boxes?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, checkbox, performance, multipleselection

In vb.net, I have a form that has a set of four Check Boxes. Each Check Box signifies that (when checked) the user wants to add a special instruction to their order. The code looks like this:

```
        If SpecialInstruction1CheckBox.Checked Then
            AddSpecialInstruction(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_1_String)
        End If
        If SpecialInstruction2CheckBox.Checked Then
            AddSpecialInstruction(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_2_String)
        End If
        If SpecialInstruction3CheckBox.Checked Then
            AddSpecialInstruction(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_3_String)
        End If
        If SpecialInstruction4CheckBox.Checked Then
            AddSpecialInstruction(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_4_String)
        End If
```

I have a feeling that this code is unnecessarily verbose, feels repetitive, and could be simplified.  How would I go about doing this, or is this not as "wrong" as it feels?

Comment: Are they a checkBoxList or four separate checkboxes?

Comment: Granted it's dated, but this article on Control Arrays might be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Tim They are four separate CheckBoxes.

Comment: Are the instructions mutually exclusive or can they be combined together? If they're mutually exclusive you could use a Select Case statement, which would exit after the first option is found. (But if that's the case, you could just use a radio button)

Comment: @Tim They can be combined together - the user can select none, any, or all of them. I actually considered using a Case instead, but because they are not mutually exclusive, I don't think it would work. This would not be a problem if VB's Case/Switch statement allowed fallthrough (as it does in certain C-variants like Java when you exclude the `break` statement

Comment: The If statements take about 3 nanoseconds.  You can write another 50 million of them without the user noticing.  Guessing at the efficiency of code is rarely productive, use a profiler.  Use it often enough and you don't have to guess anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I meant to say I feel like the code is boilerplate code, since you have to write a relatively large amount of code for a relatively simple task, not so much as in terms of speed/efficiency at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your special instructions should not be stored in separate variables.  They should be stored in an array or some other kind of list.  Then you could access them by index (e.g. `specialInstructions(1)`).

Then you can loop through the check boxes by index like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 4
    Dim box As CheckBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls("SpecialInstruction" & i.ToString() & "CheckBox"), CheckBox)
    If box.Checked Then list.Add(specialInstructions(i))
Next
```

Alternatively, you could store references to your check boxes in an array and then loop through them more easily, for instance:

```
Dim checkBoxes() As CheckBox = {
    SpecialInstruction1CheckBox,
    SpecialInstruction2CheckBox,
    SpecialInstruction3CheckBox,
    SpecialInstruction4CheckBox}

' ...

For i As Integer = 0 to checkBoxes.Length - 1
    If checkBoxes(i).Checked Then list.Add(specialInstructions(i))
Next
```

Another option would be to store the special instructions in the `Tag` property of each check box, then you could just retrieve the value from the control, like this:

```
For Each i As CheckBox In checkBoxes
    If i.Checked Then list.Add(i.Tag)
Next
```

But that only makes sense if you don't need to reuse those special instructions values elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Capitals suggests that instructions are actually constants, but yes, arrays are an interesting solution if that's possible. Of course all instructions must be bound to checkboxes though.

Comment: I really would not recommend the first alternative, though. Browsing through controls by name will make code shorter, but *not* optimal.

Comment: @Crono, I agree.  I far prefer the latter option of storing the references in an array.  Buy "optimal" depends on what one is trying to achieve.

Comment: Well given that the OP worries about efficiency on his actual code (which isn't so bad) I would say he should feel concerned about making it less performant. :p

Comment: @Crono Well, since "unefficient" isn't actually a word, I didn't want to presume what that might mean :)

Comment: Ah, it should be an *i* rather than *u* there! Didn't knew that (not my language) but I will sure remember it now, thanks! :)

Comment: I _definitely_ would have used an array for holding those constant values (each one of them holds a string literal having to do with optional instructions for an order, such as "Keep refrigerated" or "Leave at UPS store for pickup"), but I'm not sure that my instructor (for college) would consider it okay, since Arrays (at least in vb.net) do not hold constant values. Is there a way that you can protect an array of values from further changes after it's initialization?

Comment: Also, this is the answer I was exactly looking for - it took me a minute, but this is definitely the type of thing that arrays were made for. I'm still learning about data structures, so I don't fully understand what's going on in this code, but this I know this is the type of thing I had in mind - grouping like elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code isn't *that* bad in itself. It mainly depends on what `AddSpecialInstruction` does, exactly. Depending on your specifics it might be better to pass it a list of string instructions instead:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)

If SpecialInstruction1CheckBox.Checked Then list.Add(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_1_String)
If SpecialInstruction2CheckBox.Checked Then list.Add(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_2_String)
If SpecialInstruction3CheckBox.Checked Then list.Add(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_3_String)
If SpecialInstruction4CheckBox.Checked Then list.Add(SPECIAL_INSTRUCTION_4_String)

AddSpecialInstructions(list)
```

Since you also required code shrinking, I made `If` statements holding on one line. Shorter variable names would help on that too.